# How to see all the people that clicked Like?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there a way to see who clicked on the FACEBOOK `Like` BUTTON?

In the settings box of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like I can check the `Show faces option`, but then I can see just who of my friends clicked the `Like` button but I want to see all the people that clicked `Like`.

Is there any option?

Answer (score 0):

show_faces only shows the faces of your friends that have liked the same page/object. It will not show the faces of non-friends who have liked the object/page.

Comment: Hi. I'd like to ask you something about Facebook, as about work, not about programming. Do I have chance to catch you privately?

Comment: I don't know your e-mail. I have sent you FB message

Comment: Does it matter if I send it to fb.com or facebook.com?

Comment: Sent it to both, sorry. I thought you want to cut out domain because of crawlers